# How to get a textbox for an item in longlist selector for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a wp7 application using longlist selector.  My requirement is to change font of only some items on the screen.  For this i need to get the text box control for the item.

The textbox is a part of item template of the long list selector.
The items to be modified change with the scroll.

I tried using the Link event. here i can find the contentpresenter for the item being added. But how can i get the textbox from the content presenter.

Any one can help with this?  pls.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching for the TextBlock that gets generated - provide your own in the ItemTemplate/DataTemplate and set its font through binding to an item in the ItemsSource. You can use a converter to determine the font or provide the font directly in each item of the bound collection.